Find a specific group of 3 amino-acid letters in a sequence. If either one is at that location print 1 if not print 0. Print under the names
I have 3 block of sequences if I look at position 234 if there is either a V, I, E in that position print 1 if not print 0. The output would have the names of the amino acids and either a 1 or 0 under each name. In this case, each amino-acid would have three either 1s or 0s under it. For example, the output would look like:
Valine  Isoleucine  Glutamic Acid
0       0           0
1       0           0
0       1           0        

The code gives the correct answers, but the output would be a vertical line of 1s and 0s. Any help is appreciated.
v_list = []
i_list = []
e_list = []
amino_list = 'Valine','Isoleucine' ,'Glutaminc Acid'
content = fasta.read()
print('Valine'+'\t'+'Isoleucine'+'\t'+ 'Glutamic Acid'+'\n')
for line in content.split(">"):
    if re.search(r"fibroblast growth factor receptor 1 isoform", line):
        sequence = re.sub('NP.*]', '', line)
        amino = sequence[4]
        if amino in ['V']:
            v_list.append(1)
        else:
            v_list.append(0)
        if amino in ['I']:
            i_list.append(1)
        else:
            i_list.append(0)
        if amino in ['E']:
            e_list.append(1)
        else:
            e_list.append(0)

for row in v_list:
    print row


i think that this should work
for i in range(len(v_list)):
    print(f"{v_list[i]}\t{i_list[i]}\t{e_list[i]}")

you can adjust the space between each column by adding or removing tabs \t
